# Why my dictionary comprehension only change the first key/value

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I'm new to python and I wonder why this simple code does not return all the 3 keys/values of my dictionary ?
I am trying to create a dictionary and then reverse it .

```
employees = ['Kelly', 'Emma', 'John']

myNewDict1=dict.fromkeys(employees,"Hi")

newDict2 = { ky: vl for vl, ky in myNewDict1.items() } 

print(newDict2.items())
```

Here is what I see as result in my terminal :

*dict_items([('Hi', 'John')])*

While I expect to see all the three keys/values reversed .

Comment: Because keys should be unique that's why..

Comment: You can only have one value for a given key in a dictionary.

Comment: "While I expect to see all the three keys/values reversed." What would you expect the value of ``newDict2["Hi"]`` to be, then?

Comment: Try this way, `newDict2 = {'Hi': employees } 
print(newDict2.items())` Only this is possible..

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ Exactly that was the problem, thanks for your help.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, got it

Comment: @MisterMiyagi just found the problem. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach, using a dictionary it's not possible but you can use a tuple..

```
employees = ['Kelly', 'Emma', 'John']
print([('Hi', emp) for emp in employees])
```

Or One liner,

```
print(list(map(lambda x: ('Hi',x), ['Kelly', 'Emma', 'John'])))
```

**Output:**

```
[('Hi', 'Kelly'), ('Hi', 'Emma'), ('Hi', 'John')]
```